# how to get the reference to parent when binding using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, this, event-binding

I had to bind an event like this

```js
$("div").on("click", "li",function() {
  var div= $(this).parent().parent(); //this is what i'm using
  //.....
});
```

on

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

now, if $(this) refers to the 'li' then what refers to the parent 'div' on which the .on() has been performed?

Comment: Use `closest`, `$(this).closest('div');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to use [event.delegateTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) if you want specifically the `div` on which the event fired :

```
$("div").on("click", "li",function(e) {
  var $div= $(e.delegateTarget);
});
```

Comment: Thanks :). I think this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```
$("div").on("click", "li",function() {
  var div = $(this).closest('div');
  //.....
});
```